# Ogre: Issues creating a simple text ui

Tags: user-interface, ogre, ogre3d

I am trying to make a simple ui that has some text on it. I can create an empty panel and display that, however there is a runtime error when I try to create a TextAreaOverlayElement.

Error: OGRE EXCEPTIONS<5:ItemIdentityException>: Cannot locate factory for element type TextView in OverlayManager::createOverlayElement at ..........\Components\Overlay\src\OgreOverlayManager.cpp

This is the code I have created:

```
Ogre::OverlaySystem* pOverlaySystem = new Ogre::OverlaySystem();
ogre_root_->getSceneManager("MySceneManager")->addRenderQueueListener(pOverlaySystem);

std::cout << "Into ui init" << std::endl;
Ogre::OverlayManager& overlayManager = Ogre::OverlayManager::getSingleton();
std::cout << "Got singleton" << std::endl;

     // Create an overlay
     Ogre::Overlay* overlay = overlayManager.create( "OverlayName" );

     // Create a panel
     Ogre::OverlayContainer* panel = static_cast<Ogre::OverlayContainer*>( overlayManager.createOverlayElement( "Panel", "PanelName" ) );
     panel->setPosition( 0.5, 0.5);
     panel->setDimensions( 0.1, 0.1 );
     panel->setMaterialName( "BaseWhite" );
     // Add the panel to the overlay
     //Breaks on next line
     Ogre::TextAreaOverlayElement* text = (Ogre::TextAreaOverlayElement*)((Ogre::OverlayContainer*)overlayManager.createOverlayElement("TextView", "TextArea"));

     overlay->add2D( panel );

     // Show the overlay
     overlay->show();
```

If anyone knows what might be causing this or a workaround I would really appreciate it! I have been banging my head against the desk trying to figure this one out!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that it cannot find such overlay element factory as "TextView".

Which is absolutely true (unless you define one)

The signature of `createOverlayElement` is as follows ([See reference manual of 1.9](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_overlay_manager.html#a58166a773d27c22437323e8ef710406b)):

```cpp
OverlayElement* Ogre::OverlayManager::createOverlayElement(
  const String& typeName, 
  const String &instanceName, 
  bool isTemplate = false
)
```

Thus, you should define overlay element **type** in the first place and your picked name as second.

Try the following for your case:

```cpp
Ogre::TextAreaOverlayElement* text = 
  static_cast<Ogre::TextAreaOverlayElement*>(
  overlayManager.createOverlayElement("TextArea", "TextView"));
```

---

Also, you miss to add your `text` to your `panel`. Call

```cpp
panel->addChild(text);
```